# How to animate UIImageView scale but keep its image unchanged?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, animation, uiimageview

I have a circle `UIImageView` with a user picture as an image.
I need to implement an animation - to make it possible to scale `UIImageView` down/up but keep its image unchanged.
I have tried the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0f animations: ^{
    self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
}];
```

But it changes the image scale too.
I think this is expected behavior, so I need help - how to implement such kind of animation? (Scale only `UIImageView` and keep image unchanged)

Comment: Perhaps also animate the edge insets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should animate `myImageView.frame` or `myImageView.bounds` instead. Be sure the `contentMode` is set to something that does not scale the image, such as top left or center.

Comment: Animate myImageView.bounds and set myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter; did the trick.